# Determining elements of a set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I have a couple questions on how to determine the elements in a set. I was hoping I could get an explanation on how to do these and if my answers were correct. Not really looking for answers just want to be pointed in the right direction.

a) $\{3^n | n ∈ N,n<10\}$

- $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, is it supposed to be $3^n < 10$ or simply $n < 10$? I'm lost.

---

b) $\{4^n-72(2)^n + 512 = 0 | n ∈ N\}$

- $\{3,6\}$ I got this answer by substituting $x$ for $2^n$ which gave me:
- $x^2 - 72x + 512 = 0$ from there I got  $x = 8$ or $x = 64$
- since $2^n = x$
- $2^n = 8$ or $2^n = 64$
- So, $n = 3$ or $6$

---

c) $\{n^3 - 4n^2 + 3n | n ∈ \{0,1,2,3,4\}\}$

- I'm really not sure what to do on this one. I think the subset is throwing me off. Should I factor $n$ out of the first half?

---

d) $A \times B$, where $A = \{n|n ∈ N, n/4\text{ is an integer}, n<20\}$

- no clue on this one.

---

Thanks in advance guys, really trying to wrap my head around this stuff

Comment: For (b) shouldn't you write $\{n\in N|4^n-72(2^n)+512=0\}$?

Comment: For d) - what is set $B$?

Answer (score 1):

Your first question suggests you should start by reviewing [set builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation).

The lefthand portion of the notation specifies what the elements of the set actually are. For example, $\{3^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}, n < 10\}$ says that the elements of the set are numbers of the form $3^n$.

The righthand portion of the notation further specifies any variables that might appear in the description of the elements. In our example, it says that the letter $n$ is supposed to be a natural number less than $10$.

Putting these two facts together, see if you agree with
$$
\{3^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}, n < 10\} = \{3^0, 3^1, 3^2, \dots, 3^9\}
$$
(up to ambiguity about whether $0$ is a natural number or not).

See if this example helps you to approach the others. Ask questions in the comments if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer for (a.) should be powers of 3 for $n<10$, so the set would have $3^0,3^1,..$ ect.

For (c.) the elements are going to be $n^3-4n^2+3n$ where you plug in the specified values of n.

I hope those hints help so you can fill in the blanks for the rest of them.

Comment: Also, I like the way you did (b.).  Good eye on the substitution.